# how to know the PDF file name using a CGPDFDictionaryRef object reference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an object of type `CGPDFDictionaryRef` returned somehow from a method that is considered as a part of a static library (so I do not have access to its code to modify it), however, I want to know the name of the PDF file that this dictionary object holds ? how can I query it to get the name of the file?

Comment: take a look to http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDictionary/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFDictionaryGetName, this may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Sphrosit, I have read this reference, but there is no clear answer to my request, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CGPDF* functions are a function-based mechanism to get to the series of arrays, dictionaries, integers, string and name elements in PDF documents. PDF documents themselves are really just composed of these "basic" elements. If you'd like some light reading check out the ~1500 page PDF specification sometime. As rob mayoff stated, you are basically pointing to memory once you have a CGPDFDocumentRef.

That being said, there is no value that is guaranteed within a PDF structure that will give you the filename. Download [Voyeur](https://github.com/below/PDF-Voyeur) and dig around your PDF to look around and prove me wrong (I could be).

Here's the sample of the true contents of a PDF:

[image: voyeur sample]

Comment: thank you so much for your example, I have used its way in extracting PDF Metadata and this helped me so much because I manually changed my pdf file meta data and set pdf title to be equal to the pdf file name, then I extracted the title as explained in your example. thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

There are two functions that take a `CGPDFDocumentRef` and return a `CGPDFDictionaryRef`.  They are `CGPDFDocumentGetInfo` and `CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog`.  Neither function returns a dictionary that contains the name of the original file.  Neither does the array returned by `CGPDFDocumentGetID`.

This makes sense, because you can create a `CGPDFDocumentRef` without a file, from data you get over a socket or by drawing into a `CGPDFContext` with Quartz 2D.

If you want the name of the file, you'll have to get it some other way.

Comment: I get the CGPDFDictionaryRef as you said, like this: CGPDFDictionaryRef Dic = CGPDFDocumentGetInfo(self.document); where self.document is an NSObject sub-class instance which contains some ivars, two of them are: CGPDFDocumentRef document; and CGDataProviderRef provider; however, I don't have access to this class's .m file because it's part of a static lib. so I have reached to a closed door ! :(